# How to connect html dropdown list in form with php mail?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Checkout this html with php code. How to do this? I'm a beginner.

I am working on a contact form with a dropdown menu to select an e-mail address to a particular physician. I am working from a template and I do not have much experience in PHP.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group mb-5">
  <label for="package" >Package *</label>
  <select id="package" class="form-control" name="package">
    <option class="form-control" disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="value1">pkg1</option>
    <option value="value2">pkg2</option>
    <option value="value3">pkg3</option>
    <option value="value4">pkg4</option>
    <option value="value5">pkg5</option>
    <option value="value6">pkg6</option>
    <option value="value7">pkg7</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
// Get data from form 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$message= $_POST['message'];
$package = $_POST['package'];
    switch ($package) {
        case 'value1':
        $mail_to = 'your Visiting1 email';
        break;
    case 'value2':
        $mail_to = 'your Visiting2 email';
        break;
    case 'value3':
        $mail_to = 'your Visiting3 email';
        break;
}
 
$to = "mail@mail.com";
$subject="This message came from dc-ec.in Contact page";
 
// The following text will be sent
// Name = user entered name
// Email = user entered email
// Message = user entered message

$txt ="Name = ". $name . "\r\n Email = "
    . $email . "\r\n Subject = " . $mail_to . "\r\n Subject = " . $package . "\r\n Message =" . $message;
 
$headers = "From: no-reply@domain.in" . "\r\n" .
            "CC: name@domain.in";
if($email != NULL) {
    mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
}
 
// Redirect to
header("Location:contact.html");
?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is - does the above code not work? Are there errors?

Comment: Can you show the whole form and any javascript that you might be using too please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Simple logic error? You are using `switch` correctly to set a value for `$mail_to`, but then you are using a different address in `$to`, so it’s never being used to set the address the message is going to.

Answer (score -1):

Add If condition like below to send mail as per the dropdown select

```
if($_POST['package'] == "value1")
{
    $mail->Subject = 'This message came ....'; 
    $mail->addAddress('test1@gmail.com', 'value 1');
}
else if($_POST['package'] == "value2")
{
    $mail->Subject = 'This message came from..'; 
    $mail->addAddress('test2@gmail.com', 'value 2');  
}
```

Comment: The OP is already using a switch, how is this better ?